# Are there any active reinforcement learning competitions?

Tags: artificial-intelligence, reinforcement-learning

I like doing part-time research in reinforcement learning. In recent years (up to 2009) there was a reinforcement learning competition held at [rl-competition.org](http://www.rl-competition.org/) with some very interesting problems, but this seems to have been discontinued. I'd love to improve my skills and knowledge and measure it against other enthusiasts in the field - are there still any such competitions around?

Comment: [http://programmers.stackexchange.com/](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/) might be a better place for this question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Doesn't look like it, the major people who organized it last year are busy graduating from PhD.  You could email the students who organized it last time to ask though: [Shimon Whiteson](http://staff.science.uva.nl/~whiteson/Shimon_Whiteson/Home.html), [Brian Tanner](http://research.tannerpages.com/), and [Adam White](https://webapps.cs.ualberta.ca/profile/)

Also, http://metaoptimize.com/qa is basically the stack overflow for the machine learning community, it's usually a better place for such ML-specific questions.

Comment: Great links, especially the reference to an OSQA powered site. I was just thinking how great it would be to have an open source version of Stackoverflow that didn't run on Microsoft technology. I'm glad to see someone was a few steps ahead of me.